# Creating simple widget for Android. Why is the widget always 1x1 cells big?

Tags: android

After installing on my phone (also happens on emulator), the Widget is only 1x1 cells.

I have tried uninstalling the app completely, and then installing it again, but the widget is still only 1x1 cells big when I create an instance of it.

Any ideas?

Here is my provider info XML file (callernator_widget_provider_info.xml):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<appwidget-provider xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    android:minWidth="294dp"
    android:minHeight="294dp"
    android:updatePeriodMillis="86400000"
    android:initialLayout="@layout/widgetmain"
</appwidget-provider>
```

Here is the layout file:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="32dp"
        android:text="Bertus van Zyl" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="32dp"
        android:text="Button" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button3"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="32dp"
        android:text="Button" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Here is my manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="android.callernator"
      android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="1.0">
    <uses-permission 
      android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS">
    </uses-permission>
    <application android:icon="@drawable/icon" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <receiver android:name=".CallernatorWidgetProvider" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.appwidget.action.APPWIDGET_UPDATE" />
            </intent-filter>
            <meta-data android:name="android.appwidget.provider" android:resource="@xml/callernator_widget_provider_info" />      
        </receiver> 
        <activity android:name=".CallernatorActivity" android:label="@string/app_name">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Answer (score 6):

You have closing bracket > in the wrong place in the widget provider. It should be in the end of declaration, not in the end of first row.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<appwidget-provider xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:minWidth="294dp"
    android:minHeight="294dp"
    android:updatePeriodMillis="86400000"
    android:initialLayout="@layout/widgetmain">
</appwidget-provider>
```

I had exactly the same problem - widget always appeared in 1 cell. The reason in my case was missing http:// in url of widget provider.

Remember: Widget size change will take effect after you re-add widget on your device/emulator.

Answer (score 0):

first you create your widget layout xml file..

example :: i create widget_layout.xml

`

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="1dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
     >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:text="Title"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:typeface="serif" />
</RelativeLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="1dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="1dp"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/update"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/relativeLayout2"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text=""
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:typeface="serif" />
</LinearLayout>
```

`

after add in callernator_widget_provider_info.xml...

android:initialLayout="@layout/widget_layout"

Comment: Thank you for your response. I have implemented these changes, and also updated the OP to reflect them. The widget is still only 1x1 in size.I uninstalled the installed version, restarted the phone, and installed again to make sure there are no old settings or something still floating around.

Answer (score 0):

1. On android 4.0 and above native system, if your manifest.xml has `action android:name="android.intent.action.CREATE_SHORTCUT"`, then 1x1 cells will appear.
2. And `action android:name="android.intent.action.CREATE_SHORTCUT"` is to add a shortcut when you long press home screen.

These two feature conflict with each other.